# Finding Range Of Formula With Constraint

Tags: inequality, optimization

$a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are positive such that $a^{4}+b^{4}+c^{4}+d^{4}=4$
find the range of $a^{4}+64abcd$

in the case of maximum, it's not easy for me to adjust coefficients in AM-GM.

Comment: What's the nature of $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: so sorry. they're positive.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

Since $(bcd)^{1/3}\le \left(\frac {b^4+c^4+d^4}3\right)^{1/4}$ and the equality holds if and only if $b=c=d$, the supremum of the expression $a^4+64abcd$ under the given constraint $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4=4$ is equal to the supremum of $f(a)=a^4+64a\left(\frac{4-a^4}3\right)^{3/4}$, where $0\le a\le 4^{1/4}$. Mathcad Professional 2001i can solve the equation $g(a)=f’(a)=0$ symbolically, but it claims that the symbolic result is too long to display and can place it in clipboard. The text file pasted from clipboard has size 152152 bytes. The graphical evidence suggests that the function $g$ monotonically increases on $[0; 4^{1/4}]$ and has one real root $a_0\sim 1.01187$. We have that $f(a_0)\sim 65.024$.

[image]